# How to disable/enable select according to the checkbox value

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a checkbox and select. I want to disable/enable select according to the checkbox value. I already have the if-else but I do not know how to disable/enable the select. I have tried a few codes but they are not working for me.

I have tried the below code but still cannot disable/enable the select option. My checkbox id is Checkbox and select id is trip members. I want if the checkbox value is 'individual' the select is disabled else enable

```
$('#Checkbox').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {  

   var value = $(this).val();


   if(value == 'group') {
     $('#trip_members').prop('disabled', false);
   }else if(value == 'individual') {
    $('#trip_members').prop('disabled', true);
   }else if(value == '') {
    $('#trip_members').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

My select option is like below. Is it because the id in the php the jquery cannot detect it ?

```
    <label>Trip Members</label><br> 

                 <?php
                $query = "SELECT ud.u_name,u.u_id FROM tbl_user_details as ud , tbl_user as u WHERE u.u_id = ud.u_id AND u.active=1 AND (u.g_id = 1 OR u.g_id = 2 OR u.g_id = 3 OR u.g_id = 4 OR u.g_id = 5)";

                // Successful query?
                    if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query))  {
                // If there are results returned, prepare combo-box
                    if($success = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    echo "<select class='form-control' id='trip_members' name='trip_members[]' multiple>";
                // For each item in the results...
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    // Add a new option to the combo-box

                    if (in_array($row['u_id'],$retrieved_majors2))
                    {
                       echo "<option value='$row[u_id]' selected>$row[u_name]</option>";

                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$row[u_id]'>$row[u_name]</option>";
                    }

                    // End the combo-box
                     echo "</select>";
                    }
                // No results found in the database
                    else { echo "No results found."; }
                    }
             // Error in the database
                    else { echo "Failed to connect to database."; }
                ?>
```

My checkbox code is like below

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <label>Type:</label><br>    
                 <div id="Checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" <?php if($row_RecListMileage['type'] == "individual") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  
                value="individual" name="type" id="type"> Individual</label>  

                <label> <input type="checkbox" <?php if($row_RecListMileage['type'] == "group") echo "checked='checked'"; ?> 
                 value="group" name="type" id="type"> Group</label>           
                 </div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: You can check the following fiddle for some quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/ejnd9kbo/

Comment: Please add your checkbox code. Maybe there is some issue under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting

```js
$('.check').change(function(e){
 $(this).siblings().prop('checked',false)
 var value = $(this).val();
   if(value == 'group') {
     $('#trip_members').prop('disabled', false);
   }else if(value == 'individual') {
    $('#trip_members').prop('disabled', true);
   }else if(value == '') {
    $('#trip_members').prop('disabled', false);
   }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="check" type="checkbox"   value="group"> group<br>
<input class="check" type="checkbox"   value="individual">individual<br>
<input  class="check" type="checkbox"   value=""  > none<br>
  <select id ="trip_members">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OMG ! Thanks you so much. You save my life :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code but sometimes a different approach does the trick

```
$('#Checkbox').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function()
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 'group')
    {
        $('#trip_members').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else if(value == 'individual')
    {
        $('#trip_members').addAttr('disabled');
    }
    else if(value == '')
    {
        $('#trip_members').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

**EDIT1:** I just noticed that you have multiple checkboxes and the same ID won't work. use class or data attribute to listen to the change event.

```
$('[data-checktype]').on('change', function(){}
```

Comment: I have try ur code also still cannot run. I have paste my select code. Is it because the id in php tag so the jquery cannot detect it ?

Comment: i have change it and try to put alert to know the value of checkbox is get or not. then the alert show the value of the checkbox correctly. just the select do not disable/enable